# iPhoneのバッジ数が増えない

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

現在、railsのgem 'rpush'を利用してiPhoneのwebiviewアプリに、プッシュ通知とバッジ通知の実装をしています。
実装はある程度できたのですが、２点問題が発生し解決できず本当に困っています。

・何度通知をしてもバッジ通知が１から増えない。
・webviewを開いている際にプッシュ通知が送られない。

swift側の処理は、AppDelegateファイルの中に以下のメソッドを記載しています。しかし通知を送っても動作していないようです。

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){
　　UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
}
```

Xcodeの設定は下記のようにしております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなたか知恵をお貸しくださいませ。恐れ入りますがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！！
Push NotificationsもONに設定をしているのですが。。。

Comment: 失礼しました。バッチに１がカウントされているのでONにされてますよね。

Comment: ちょっと調べてなくて自信ないですが`UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber`から値って取得できましたっけ？0(未定義)+1となっているような気が……、2を代入したらバッチ数は2になりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！！
確認したところ、バッジ数は2に増えました。恐らく何か別の問題がありそうです。。

Comment: RpushでNotificationを送る時にbadgeに0を設定していませんか？その場合、「プッシュ通知を受信する度にバッチが消えたあと、+=1で1になる」という挙動になると思います。badge=nilならPush通知の受信ではバッチが変化しなくなるはずです。

Comment: badgeには1を設定しています。nilを設定しましたところ、何度通知を送ってもバッジ数が表示されないです。。。恐らくdidReceiveRemoteNotificationのメソッドが動いていないようです。。。

Comment: すみません、バッジ数が２に増えたと確認したのはdidReceiveRemoteNotificationのメソッド内で確認したのではなく、appdelegateのapplicationDidEnterBackgroundの内にUIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1と記載をしたらバッジ数が２、３、４と増えていったということでした。失礼しました。

Comment: アプリ起動時にプッシュ通知がいくメソッドも記述しました！プッシュ通知は起動するようになりましたが、相変わらずバッジ数は増えません。。
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("willPresent")
        completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
    }

Comment: Push NotificationとBackgroundMode(Background fetch,Remote notifications)をOFFにしてもプッシュ通知が送れることが判明しました。原因はわかりません。。。